# How to sync with main net faster?

Tags: nodeos, mainnet

I'm trying to run nodeos in mainnet. I tried to download https://eosnode.tools/blocks and run `--hard-replay --wasm-runtime wabt`. It takes a long time. Is there a faster way to sync?
I have the snapshot file but can't use account history feature with the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the single-threaded nodeos just cannot process the sheer load of block data fast enough to sync in a reasonable amount of time. It is taking my node with 64GB of RAM and 3 GHz processor over 5+ days now to sync 7M of 37M. Very frustrating. We definitely need fast access to historical data through block producer infrastructure.

I am almost giving up on the local node. Have been toying with the proxy provided by eosnode.tools that automatically selects a BP with history plugin enabled. It is not ideal but works on and off.